# How to open .bds file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, file-formats, cadcorp-sis

I have a Land Registry boundary file which is in .bds (Base Dataset) format, a native file format in Cadcorp SIS. I want to open this file in QGIS. Is it possible, or do I have to do any conversions?

Comment: If you can make the file available to download then I'll happily convert it for you.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

According to Google search

Please try following options :

1.You need to convert those files as shape file (itself in Cadcorp software)

2.Launch the Cadcorp software  and try "save as" option and save as .shp so that you can open this file in QGIS.

3.Export .bds file as map-info format (.tab) then import those files in QGIS.

4.Please check [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=983&t=108506) post for moire details.

Hope it will helpful for you..

Comment: No Its not working .I downloaded the cadcrop Gis Software there itself this .bds file does not get opened? What I can DO now?